# Getting an error when Android apk is tried to deploy external device

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

```
   Launching app
$ adb push /app/build/outputs/apk/prelollipop/debug/XXX.apk /data/local/tmp/XXX.android
$ adb shell pm install -t -r "/data/local/tmp/XXX.android"
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/XXX.android-1: Package /data/app/com.ozan.android-1/base.apk code is missing]


$ adb shell pm uninstall XXX.android
Unknown failure (at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:573))
Error while Installing APK
```

I am getting this error when i try to deploy app to external device after codes successfully build on Android Studio 3.0.
Also i use Dexguard v8.1.01. However if i build the apk with dexguard .apk is successfully deploy the device. the problem is occured without dexguard build.

Any idea to fix it?

Comment: delete your build folder from app/build , Uninstall App And Install Again

Comment: thanks for the solution, but it does not work. i do your solution many time. the result is the same

Comment: are you using Firebase in your Project??

Comment: yeap. i am using it

Comment: Just ran into this myself. Any solutions?